# Error in instantiating fabcar chaincode in node, fabric 1.3

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/write_first_app.html#install-the-clients-launch-the-network) section of `fabcar` tutorial. When i run :

```
./startFabric.sh
```

It works like charm. But when i run following command to run `node.js` chaincode:

```
./startFabric.sh node
```

I get the error:

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting
>   chaincode fabcar:1.0 for transaction

I am using Fabric 1.3.0. Let me know how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked. Actually a chaincode with same name and version was existing. So i just changed the version and it worked like charm.

Comment: can you please specify, which chaincode was same as the other one?

Comment: i can't find it , i am getting following errors :  msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 127